# Gson Date Type Exception: How can i fix the exception?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i am using Gson to convert json to Java class...the Type of firstLogin  is java.util.Date

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     String lineString="{\"email\":\"sadas\",\"faith\":121,\"qq\":211,\"account\":2412,\"userName\":\"asda\",\"firstLogin\":1321362590000,\"uid\":1}";
     Gson gson=new Gson();
User user=gson.fromJson(lineString, User.class);
    System.out.println(user.getFirstLogin());
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1321362590000
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:78)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:63)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:38)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$19$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:462)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$19$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:466)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:720)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:686)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:636)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:608)
    at gsontest.GsonTest.main(GsonTest.java:22)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1321362590000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:76)
    ... 11 more
Java Result: 1
```

how to fix the problem ...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstLogin` has a long type in your json, so get it as a `long` variable from JSON and create a new `Date` using `Date(long milliseconds)` constructor.